# most popluar module in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I want to show most popular block in Drupal. 
For this, I have downloaded the *mostpopular* module from http://drupal.org/project/mostpopular. 
But this is not showing any result. How can I show the most viewed page in Drupal.

Comment: You must make sure Cron is running correct. Have you visited *Admin » Reports » Status* to see if everything is reported to work correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is statistics.module enabled and configured to log access? (Or another service the module integrates with)?

Answer (score 1):

Try also: [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) + Statistics module.